# How to add signature tabs on documents in DocuSign embedded esignature?

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am using DocuSign embedded esignature API to sign documents. It works fine when I know where to place the signature tab. However, in case of documents with different positioning of signature field this does not work (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/).

Please take a look at below examples:
In all these documents, the signature position is different. The user can sign any of the form. How can I add the signature tabs dynamically in this scenario.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULOyK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK6eN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CxxF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5wrM.png)

I have tried Fixed, AutoPlace explained [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/). But it does not work because each document has different positioning of signature field.

Note: I am not using DocuSign SDK because my application runs on older version of java.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in your account called "Anchor Population Scope" for anchor tags (AutoPlace)

It can be the document, or the envelope.

This setting is controlled by DocuSign, so you need to contact customer support to change it.

If you change it to "per-document" then you can have different anchor strings for different documents so that should solve your issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? I could not find documentation related to this.  Are you suggesting to add anchor string on each document ? If so, then it won't work for me because I cannot edit the document

Comment: if you cannot find a text differentiating the documents, you cannot use anchor strings

Comment: You can just used fixed positioning with X/Y coordinates in that case.

Comment: Thanks but that will be too much because there are 50 pdf files. Do you know if there is any property which allows user to add signature tabs themselves while signing

Comment: If you don't add any tabs to the envelopes, the users will get a drag/drop menu and can add all the tabs they want